# Compare files with Rspec. some_uploaded_file.should eq some_local_file

Tags: file-upload, rspec, comparison

With cucumber and rspec I want to determine if a certain file is updated and/or overwritten correctly. The files are images.

As a human I would simply compare the images visually. Rspec obviously cannot do this.

Comparing the original, none-scaled or cropped, image is fine.

I have tried to to download the image then compare the contents.

```
url = "http://audrey:3000/#{camping.image.url}"
online_file = open(url).read
local_file = IO.binread(File.join(Rails.root, "spec", "fixtures", image))
```

There is too much wrong with this approach. Getting the absolute url is not easy or portable, fetching over the network is slow, comparing binaries seems ugly.

How should I compare images?